# Property 'meals' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.ts(2339)

Tags: react-native, redux

Do anyone knows why I get this error?
I am using useSelector() method from react-redux and trying to get my list of favorite meals from my store where I stored all of my meals but it is giving me this error(the above error).
Do you know what is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
  const favoriteMeals = useSelector((state) => state.meals.favoritsMeals);
  const renderMealItem = (itemData) => {
    const isFavorite = favoriteMeals.find(
      (meal) => meal.id === itemData.item.id
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your root Reducer if there is any "meals" reducer or not, it's probably miss character in "meals" in root Reducer

Comment: I have checked that, there is no miss character in  "meals" in root Reducer.

Comment: Are you using toolkit or action/reducer ?

Comment: I'm using action/reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how `useSelector` should be used with TS: [Redux documentation about useSelector and TS](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript/#typing-the-useselector-hook)

It means, in some `types.d.ts` you could write something like:

```
interface favMealsInterface {
    ...
}

type MealsState = {
    favoriteMeals: favMealsInterface[]
}

export interface RootState {
    meals: MealsState
}
```

and then probably use useSelector like this:

```
const { favoriteMeals } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.meals);
```

At least something like this worked for me.
I took advice from [Russian StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088974/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-useselector-%D0%B2-react-redux-typescript?newreg=4f28b5d18aaa433ab0bd3bd021b9c3d7)